# What is the equivalent of LocalAppData on Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, performance, storage, local

On Windows, there are two separate paths to store user data, depending on the use case:

- `%APPDATA% C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming`
- `%LOCALAPPDATA% C:\Users\username\LocalAppData\Roaming`

AppData is the main user profile that can be shared between machines. It is expected to be on a network drive when in an entreprise context with Active Directory.

LocalAppData is the equivalent place, that is never on a network drive. The distinction is very important for applications that process large files or lots of small files, that are not meant to be shared and not meant to be backed up, like my application.

In my experience Linux only has a home directory `$HOME /home/username`. The home directory can be mounted on NFS to be shared between Linux machines. Some of my users have their home directory on NFS and it's problematic because NFS is slow and inefficient.

I am trying to figure out what is the equivalent of LocalAppData on Linux.

Some examples where the distinction is very important. Chrome is storing the user configuration in AppData and the browser cache in LocalAppData. JetBrains IDE is storing the user configuration in AppData and autocompletion introspection data in LocalAppdata.

Comment: Take a look at [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)